# How do I pause or continue a page animation when going to another tab in the browser?

Tags: animation

I don't code so asking for help :-)  Hi, I have an issue for a page animation with a couple of interactions.  How do I insert a code snippet to tell the browser to either continue or pause the animation, when a user opens/clicks another tab.

Right now, the animation pauses for the first part, but the subsequent interactions keep going.  And it's a jumbled mess.

What is the easiest/simple way to do this?  Can someone share the full/complete code snippet to accomplish this?  I've been searching for hours and can't seem to find the right solution.

I'm using Webflow for the site.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks away from a window, certain events are fired off. You can add event handlers to your window object that respond to these events.

You probably want to listen for 'focus' and 'blur' events. JavaScript:

```
    window.addEventListener('blur', function (evt) {
      // turn off your animation here
    });

    window.addEventListener('focus', function (evt) {
      // turn on your animation here
    });
```

Documentation on [window blur event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/blur_event), [window focus event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus_event), [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

I have a simple page that reports all window events, it might be useful:

https://terrymorse.com/coding/windowevents/index.html